# I can't seem to add bounties

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

Some of my questions say "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

But I can't seem to find an bounty option on them.
I have used bounties in the past.

Comment: Do you have a bounty running at the moment? There can be only one at a time

Comment: Yes I do thanks I must of missed that in the faq.

Comment: Pekka: If you want to put that in the form of an answer for me to accept I'd mark that (otherwise I'll close this question).

Comment: @Pekka Read Roman's comment ^^^.

Comment: Interesting that you still see the same nudge text at a time when the system knows you can't actually offer a bounty. Probably too minor for the team to fix, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a bounty running at the moment?

There can be only one at a time.